# Windows 8.1 doesn't recognize my graphics card

Tags: resolution, hdmi, amd-radeon, display-driver

I have purchased Monitor is a **Dell S2240L 21.5 inch LED Backlit LCD Monitor** Max resolution 1920 x 1080 pixels, HDMI with mother board **Gigabyte GA-78LMT-USB3 Motherboard** and processor **AMD FX 8350 AMD FX Processor Black Edition**.

After installing Windows 8.1 OS.  I noticed that the resolution was wrong (it was 1400 x 1050 pixels and my monitor max resolution is 1920 x 1080 pixels),I went To device Manager and I opened the *Display Adapters* and It said: **Microsoft Basic Display Adapter**.

I tried everything inserting my driver cd and installing all drivers, didn't help anything..

**Integrated Graphics card:** ATI Radeon HD 3000 graphics

Full display details:

[image: dxdiag]

Comment: In **Device Manager**, does it show any problems for display adapters?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are missing the drivers for your video adapter.

[image]

Install the motherboard drivers, mainly the chipset and display adatper and you should see the name change to something other than Microsoft Basic Display Adapter.

http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4305#dl

This motherboard has a built in VGA adapter.  The link above is to download and install the drivers.

Comment: actually i am looking into this and that seems to be an AMD workstation CPU, not an APU with built in video processor.  You need to get a separate video card or an APU with a built in video processor.

Comment: Do I need to buy separate video processor?

Comment: Either an AMD APU or a video card.  Are you looking to do gaming with this PC?

Comment: No, I am not looking to do gaming

Comment: I just saw the motherboard has an integrated ATI Radeon HD 3000 graphics  chip.  Hang on, i am getting you a link to gigabyte to download and install drivers.

Comment: http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4305#dl

Comment: Go there, enter your operating system, and download and install the VGA driver.

Comment: I would do the chipset, audio, and LAN too just to make sure all your drivers are updated to the latest version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27055/discussion-between-peter-parker-and-brian).

Answer (score 0):

After updating OS from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 the issue was resolved.
Now OS is able to detect my integrated graphics card as follows.

[image]

> I think the issue with Windows 8.1

Answer (score -1):

OK, you definitely can fix this issue!

(Can not understand what the problem is with win 8.1 but they failed to load proper driver after offered free upgrade win8->win8.1, and loaded standard driver dated 2006)

1. Just download from gigabyte web page drivers for your motherboard vga adapter (http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5195#dl). There is no vga drivers above windows7. So download vga drivers for win7.
2. Extract to easy access location
3. Go to Device Manager, pick up your present vga device and click update driver software->browse for driver software->navigate to extracted folder and select it. Be sure option Include sub-folders is checked.
4. Press Next.
5. You are done!

Can check properties via DirecX. Open Run, type in dxdiag and press enter.